# Source for USGS (probably not) seismic map of La Habra, California (Publication Date April 15, 1998)

Tags: seismology, earth-observation, mapping

I'm trying to find to original source (especially high quality version) of this conservation seismic map. I know that it probably came from USGS (or not) but looks like it out of print? I tried to search for the map on USGS.gov but no result so far. IS there  anything else I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This map appears to have been produced by the California Geological Survey (a state agency) as a GIS cover incorporating two specific coverage layers, namely, 1) Seismic Hazards Program - Landslide Zones, and 2) Seismic Hazards Program - Liquefaction Zones.  The map viewer for selecting GIS layers and observing available mapped information is can be accessed [here](https://maps.conservation.ca.gov/cgs/DataViewer/). An extract is shown below. Simply go to site and select the coverages you wish to see...

[image: La Habra extract CGS data viewer]